# Select row by its list index in r

Tags: r

I would like to extract the row by its list index. I tried to search in stackoverflow but most of the solution only works for certain index (e.g. `sapply(list,"[[,1)` (This select every first row) or `sapply(list,"[,1:2)` (This select every first and second rows)).

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-data.frame(matrix(runif(9),ncol=3))
y<-data.frame(matrix(runif(9),ncol=3))
z<-data.frame(matrix(runif(9),ncol=3))

lst<-list(x,y,z)

lst
[[1]]
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.2875775 0.8830174 0.5281055
2 0.7883051 0.9404673 0.8924190
3 0.4089769 0.0455565 0.5514350

[[2]]
         X1        X2         X3
1 0.4566147 0.6775706 0.89982497
2 0.9568333 0.5726334 0.24608773
3 0.4533342 0.1029247 0.04205953

[[3]]
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.3279207 0.6928034 0.6557058
2 0.9545036 0.6405068 0.7085305
3 0.8895393 0.9942698 0.5440660
```

Desired output:

```
lst
[[1]] #select first row
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.2875775 0.8830174 0.5281055

[[2]] #select second row
         X1        X2         X3
1 0.9568333 0.5726334 0.24608773

[[3]] #select third row
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.8895393 0.9942698 0.5440660
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `imap`.  As the `list` is unnamed, the `.y` will be the sequence index of the `list`, which we used in `slice` to subset the rows

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap(lst, ~ .x %>%
     slice(.y))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.2875775 0.8830174 0.5281055

[[2]]
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.9568333 0.5726334 0.2460877

[[3]]
         X1        X2       X3
1 0.8895393 0.9942698 0.544066
```

---

Or using `base R` with `Map`

```
Map(function(x, i) x[i,], lst, seq_along(lst))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.2875775 0.8830174 0.5281055

[[2]]
         X1        X2        X3
2 0.9568333 0.5726334 0.2460877

[[3]]
         X1        X2       X3
3 0.8895393 0.9942698 0.544066
```

Comment: Map approach works for me. Thank you!